# Problems with markers in Mapview

Tags: python, python-3.x, maps, kivy, markers

I am trying to use some basic functions of the library Mapview. [here's the documentation](https://mapview.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I just need to set the map on a certain city and then to create some markers (the coordinates will be given from another function).
This is my code:

```
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapView, MapMarker
from kivy.app import App

class MapViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        map = MapView(zoom=11, lat=50.6394, lon=3.057, double_tap_zoom = True)
        marker_1 = MapMarker(lon=50.6394, lat=3.057)
        map.add_marker(marker_1)
        return map

MapViewApp().run()
```

However a problem occurs.
The coordinates should point a city in France - Lille.
It centers the map on Lille but the marker appears somewhere in Africa.
How can it be fixed?[image: The marker vs France]

Comment: It's a typo, latitude and longitude are inverted in the marker, should be `marker_1 = MapMarker(lat=50.6394, lon=3.057)`

Comment: @FJSevilla Thank you! I feel pretty embarased now! :)

Answer (score 0):

you may use mapview.center_on(50.6394, 3.057)